# Embedded tomcat won't resolve Spring application resource bundle for message source

Tags: spring, maven, properties-file, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am experiencing trouble with my embedded tomcat: when I run my Spring app using the embedded Tomcat, it seems the properties are not resolved.

Even if the properties file are loaded:

```
INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from file [/home/julien/Documents/donnees/projets/Site-Rencontres/java/target/classes/META-INF/i18n/application.properties]
```

The resource bundles are not found:

```
WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [/META-INF/i18n/application] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /META-INF/i18n/application, locale fr
```

However, when I run my app from Eclipse/STS, I have no such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially sorted the problem. By removing the leading slashes here (in the Spring config):

```
<property name="basenames" value="/META-INF/i18n/application,/META-INF/i18n/messages" />
```

to obtain this:

```
<property name="basenames" value="META-INF/i18n/application,META-INF/i18n/messages" />
```

the problem was resolved.

However what caused the **difference of behavior between embedded Tomcat and standard Tomcat** in the first place, I don't explain...